# Why am I unable to access an element of a window in PyWinAuto?

Tags: automation, ui-automation, pywinauto

I am trying to get access of all the children in a ListBox that is inside an app window. But I am unable to access it by any attribute.

I used print_control_identifiers() to get the UI tree of the app window.
I need to access this listbox from the UI tree :

```
   | ListBox - ''    (L455, T342, R1466, B567)
   | ['ListBox', 'AppsListBox']
   |    | 
   |    | ListItem - ''    (L455, T342, R605, B537)
   |    | ['ListItem', 'AppsListItem', 'ListItemAdd To Favorites', 'ListItemNotepad', 'ListItemDetails']
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | Hyperlink - 'Notepad'    (L497, T373, R563, B449)
   |    |    | ['Hyperlink3', 'Notepad', 'NotepadHyperlink', 'Notepad0', 'Notepad1', 'NotepadHyperlink0', 'NotepadHyperlink1']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Notepad", control_type="Hyperlink")
   |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    | Image - 'Notepad'    (L502, T377, R558, B433)
   |    |    |    |    | ['Notepad2', 'Image', 'NotepadImage']
   |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Notepad", control_type="Image")
   |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    | Hyperlink - 'Notepad'    (L456, T449, R604, B494)
   |    |    |    | ['Hyperlink4', 'Notepad3', 'NotepadHyperlink2']
   |    |    |    | child_window(title="Notepad", control_type="Hyperlink")
```

Since there is no child_window specification of the listbox, I tried to use auto_id and control_type to access the element. Unfortunately, both of those identifiers were unable to find that list.

What attribute should I use to get access to the listbox?